# Opportunity to change salary and position from development to validation

Tags: career-development, job-change

I'm in mess because until today I'm working in I don't know how to call small or medium team of developers there was 7-8 devs and one tester. I'm there software developer in web apps so i was programming in sql, javascript, c#... I've got there almost free hand to design software as I want etc.

But yesterday called me well known big international company to work for them as a Software engineer in tests, and they wan't to double my wage... I really don't know what to do because I'm working as software developer barely a year and in that big company I'll be working in validation team and writing tests in c# for programs wroted in c++.

I would like others to tell me is it possible to get promotion from validation team to dev's team in corporations? And isn't it maybe step back you know writing tests? Would you change your job from delevopment to writing automatic tests?

Thank you for your anwser :)

Clarifying note: i'm after whole process of interview, and they offered me this job position in that corporation...

Comment: I can't speak if it's the case for intel but for some big compagies it easier to change after you've set a foot in (by doing testing). You will probably see many position been open for employee before they are open for external applicant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewritten answer:

The fact that they made you an offer indicates that they made a decision that you are qualified for the job and that you will be successful on the job.

You have to decide for yourself:

1. If you decide to stay, what will you learn in terms of skills and get in terms of work experience by staying that will be of value to your next employer? Are you willing to put up with fact that you are underpaid - in fact, grossly underpaid, as a justification for staying?
2. The fact that the offer in effect doubles your salary is an indicator that you are not exactly overpaid in your current job. One option is that you learn just as much and do as much as you are doing now, but working for some other employer. But you have to develop that option by getting an offer by that other employer, and developing that option requires you to spend time searching and interviewing.
3. If you decide to leave, what do you expect to learn and do in terms of testing that you think will be of value to your career and your next employer, and does what you expect to learn and do justify the lateral jump? The doubling of salary alone would justify to almost every one of your next employers why you decided to change jobs.

I am not really interested in giving you the pre-packaged answer that you seek. Instead, I will pose the question to you: you clearly intend to switch back to the dev from testing. Can you convince a future prospective employer that the experience and skills you will acquire in testing will be valuable in a dev context to that employer? If you can, then you answered your own question. If you think that I just placed on you the onus of making the case, your thinking is correct.

It goes back to the responsibility of managing your career being your responsibility not any of your employers no matter how well meaning they are. Employers hire you because they have a specific need and they expect something out of you. In turn, you accept an offer because you have worked out what you want out of them.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specific but i'm after whole process of interview, and they offered me this job position in that corporation...

Comment: @matt2515 No, you weren't specific, you did not disclose a critical fact and that's how I got misled. Now, I have to entirely rethink and rewrite my answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer and sorry for trouble of rewriting your answer. I having hard time because that big company is intel. So when I was a kid and I was driving near them building I always want it. But you have 100% right I have to be responsible and switching careere from SDE to SDET is not exactly step forward but rather stopping in one place or side jump. And to be honest with you my careere just begins because I just turned 24 and I parallel studying in university and working as dev since 10 months and as everyone I like to have money but right now I should be responsible in

Comment: @matt2515 It can be a step forward if you can make the argument that experience gained doing testing is invaluable to your professional development as a software engineer, as many a developer with testing experience has made. One to three years of experience doing testing looks good but anything like five years may get you typecast as a tester. And again, the company is Intel.

Comment: I think I'll try my self in new role as you said 1-2 years, and then I'll try to change my position from SDET to SDE. In a middle of time I'll be working on some small project in another firm as web developer... Thank you @Vietnhi for your help!